# Tengo este este error, No tiene suficiente espacio libre en /var/cache/apt/archives/

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Estoy tratando de instalar libxml2-dev y libxslt1-dev y no me deja.
Utilice el siguiente comando:

`apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev`,

también probé de a uno y mismo error de espacio insuficiente

obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes adicionales:
  icu-devtools libicu-dev
Paquetes sugeridos:
  icu-doc pkg-config
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes NUEVOS:
  icu-devtools libicu-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
0 actualizados, 4 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 5 no actualizados.
Se necesita descargar 11,1 MB de archivos.
Se utilizarán 51,7 MB de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
E: No tiene suficiente espacio libre en /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

Para `E:No tiene suficiente espacio libre en /var/cache/apt/archives/`

utilicé estos:

`du -sh /var/cache/apt/archives` --> para ver el tamaño de fichero, me da como resultado: `76K /var/cache/apt/archives`

```
sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Una vez ejecutados estos comando de arriba, ejecuto nuevamente `du -sh /var/cache/apt/archives` y me da como resultado el mismo tamaño que al principio `76K /var/cache/apt/archives`

Pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema, también borré los tmp pero nada me ha funcionado para quitar el error.

Si me pueden ayudar, se los agradecería

Tengo esta versión de Kali:

> PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
>
> NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
>
> VERSION="2020.3"

Comment: ¿Qué te arroja el comando `df -h /`?

Comment: Más que el Sistema Operativo o el comando hay que revisar si tienes espacio en tus particiones.

Answer (score -1):

Hola me paso igual quería actualizar con sudo apt update , luego sudo apt upgrade y no me dejaba por el espacio con el mismo error.

Le agrege el apt-get y me actualizo bien.

_Calculo que lo habrás intentado de las dos maneras pero justo cuando buscaba la solución a eso me funciono agregarle el -get.

Saludos y Espero lo puedas solucionar!